# Get the category name,permalink and description

Tags: php, wordpress

So I need to list some categories, and I can list them with `wp_list_categories` but i also need the description for that category, i need to do something like this:

```
<a href="permalink">Category name</a>
The description here
```

And right now I'm stuck i don't know how to do this with wordpress

Comment: Start to learn that a lot of information is available in the codex, for example this function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/category_description

Comment: I know i tried allready, but how can i implement this with `wp_list_categories`

Comment: Well you need to find a way to combine two functions. That is normally done with help of variables and control structures. You find those explained in the php manual: http://php.net/manual as that is not specific to wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

This page shows how to add the Category Description: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/category_description

It should have everything you need there, but for quick reference, the simplest way is:

```
<?php echo category_description(); ?>
```

(within the Wordpress loop)

*EDIT*
Just realized since you're combining this with wp_list_categories(), you'll have to create a loop that goes through the categoriy lists and displays the title and the description.

Try this Wordpress support page: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/have-wp_list_categories-output-the-category-descpription

Comment: I'm not in the loop, outside the loop

Comment: Check out the get_categories page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories   Scroll down and you'll see an example that shows what you're looking for.

Comment: See my recent edit with a link to the support page...has tons of examples there for exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

```
    <?php 
        foreach(get_categories() as $category):
            echo $category->cat_name;
        echo category_description($category->cat_ID);
        endforeach;
    ?>
```